# Using Squid to forward traffic to specific IP address

Tags: proxy, squid

I have an issue I can't seem to figure how to solve. I am thinking of using Squid for this but not 100% sure how to configure. A developer is writing a script that will request an XML file from a secure web server.

The script will live in a cloud-based application and will send the request for this XML file to the web server, the script will then translate the XML file content into readable data using API calls and presented to the user in the application.

The problem is the following:

The application server (A) its load balanced and the IP address may not always be the same. We do not own this app server only have access to APIs
The Web server (B) that owns the XML is behind a firewall and it has to specify the incoming IP address allowed to access this content
I am thinking I would have to configure reverse proxy on Squid that will receive the script/request from any IP address (preferably from the application servers only) and would have to forward the exact request to the IP address of the Web server that owns the XML file.

This means that I would have to specify the IP address of the proxy server rather than the web server in the script and somehow allow the proxy server to know it needs to forward it to the web server.

I'm not sure how to do this securely since in this scenario as ANY external IP address coming the proxy server will be forwarded over.

(A) App server ======> Squid Proxy =======> (B) Webserver

I hope this makes sense thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer?